# Can I spy on a dependency to the system under test - even if it is not a direct dependency of the SUT?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine2.0

My question relates to Jasmine. Say I have the following graph of dependencies in an application:

```
SystemUnderTest --> Dependency1 --> Dependency2 --> DependencyN
```

Can I spy on **`DependencyN`** even if it is not a direct dependency to the system under test (`SystemUnderTest`) but rather a transitive dependency (only `Dependency1` is a direct dependency above)?

Comment: Are you using DI all along the path? Without knowing more info - simple answer is YES if you use DI, NO if any of the dependencies in the chain "new up" any sub dependencies directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. In frameworks like AngularJS or Angular2 that make use of dependency injection, mocking (or spying on methods of) a service will inject the mocked version for any other components or child components that would normally use this same service.